# Printing regression results from python statsmodel into a Excel worksheet

Tags: python, statistics, export-to-excel, statsmodels

My job requires running several regressions on different types of data and then need to present these results on a presentation - I use Powerpoint and they link very well to my Excel objects such as charts and tables

Is there a way to print the results into a specific set of cells in an existing worksheet?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(y,x)
results = model.fit()
```

Would like to send the regression result.params into column B for example. Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

dta = sm.datasets.longley.load_pandas()
dta.exog['constant'] = 1

res = sm.OLS(dta.endog, dta.exog).fit()

df = pd.concat((res.params, res.tvalues), axis=1)

df.rename(columns={0: 'beta', 1: 't'}).to_excel('output.xls', 'sheet1')
```

Comment: You'll need the excel dependencies installed for pandas. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/install.html#optional-dependencies

Comment: See the docstring of `to_excel` for printing in to an open workbook. I assume that will get you to where you need to be.